# Which underlying mechanisms does JHipster use for code generation

Tags: jhipster

I have some questions regarding the JHipster code generator, or to be more specific:
Which underlaying mechanisms does JHipster use to generate it's Code? I can't find any information regarding this topic on their website. I'm currently writing a Bachelors Thesis about JHipster and need some info about the "low-level" mechanics on Jhipster i.e how this works, or if there are some frameworks for generation in use which i can look into.

If StackOverflow is the wrong place for questions like this, please tell me where I can ask my questions.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster code generator runs on nodejs and builds on top of yeoman. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-generator-development-setup